# How I can get information about the OpenSearch from python

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm trying to get some information about my OpenSearch with python, but the `info()` does not provide useful details.
there is a way to get the GET `_cluster/stats` and "search latency", "indexing latency"?